# El while true ejecuta solo el primer comando y no sigue indefina mente a menos que complete el segundo comando

Tags: python, arduino, sintaxis

Estoy intentando enviar datos desde el arduino a la raspberry, el arduino envía los datos de la temperatura a la raspberry, y a su vez la raspberry envia un caracter al arduino para encender o apagar el led. El problema viene en el momento en que el raspberry debe imprimir los datos de la temperatura, y a su vez controlar el led.

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

def SENSOR():
      temp = arduino.readline()
      temperatura = temp.decode('utf-8').strip()
      print(temperatura)
def led():
      comando = input() #Input
      arduino.write(comando.encode()) #Mandar un comando hacia Arduino
      if comando == 'A':
          print('LED ENCENDIDO')
      elif comando == 'a':
          print('LED APAGADO')
while True:
      SENSOR()
      led()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. `input` no es asincronico. Cuando se ejecuta, "traba" al codigo esperando a que el usuario ingrese el comando. Tendrías que encontrar la manera de pedirle el comando al usuario de forma asincrónica, u obtener la temperatura de forma asincronica. Eso lo podrías lograr con Threads.

Comment: Que forma nos sugiere para solucionar el problema del input ?

Comment: Encontrar la forma de que el sensor mida la temperatura asincronicamente. Estoy probando ahora mismo con crear una tarea separada para lograrlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se debe a que el comando `input` "traba" el código. Este se queda esperando a que el usuario presione enter y entonces tu programa no guarda los datos del sensor.
Logré con el modulo incluido `threading` hacer un contador que sigue funcionando mientras el input espera a que el usuario ingrese algo.
Esto te podría servir de base para lograr lo que deseas. O eso espero.

```
from threading import Thread
import logging

contador = 0
    
def led():
    while True:
        comando = input() #Input
        if comando == 'A':
          print('LED ENCENDIDO')
        elif comando == 'a':
          print('LED APAGADO')

        print(contador)


t=Thread(target=led)
t.start()

while True:
    contador += 1
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada David Laime